# use tesseract v3 to create pdf documents with searcheable text command line

Tags: linux, command-line, ocr, tesseract

We are using tessereact to extract text from tiff scanned documents, We launch this using the tesseract command line options, however we would like to use the Tesseract V3.0 to convert this tiff scanned docs into PDF with searcheable text, and also we would need to get this using command line.

Our system is an Ubuntu 12 Server, any ideas about how to get this? We have been searching in the Tesseract V3.0 Datasheet but we have not been able to understand it correctly.

Did any of you guys got something similar?

Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will need [Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) v3.03 to produce searchable PDF.

Comment: Hi there Thanks a lot for the clarification, but where can I donwload the release to install in our ubuntu server, and where can we find the manual or user guide? I have been checking the tesseract site but I did not find the release. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It will ship in Ubuntu 14.04. Or you can build from the [source](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/source/checkout). The command is: `tesseract yourimage outfile pdf`